# Cleaning GET query urls with PHP

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've used mod_rewrite to rewrite my get query urls from /news?news_id=6 to /news/6. But now I'd like to be able to also do the same for when somebody submits a form using a get method. Right now when you submit a form it still directs you to /news/news_id=6 instead of /news/6, how would I be able to clean the get query url? I'm pretty sure this can't be done using mod_rewrite (please correct me if you can do so), so I imagine you'd need to use either Javascript or PHP. I've been trying to do this with PHP and so far I've done as follows:

```
 if (!empty($_GET['news_id'])) {
    $redirecturl = "/news/" . $_GET['news_id'];
    $redirecturl = str_replace(" ", "-", $redirecturl);
    header('Location: ' . $redirecturl, true, 303);
    die();
}
```

However this results in an error on the browser which says "localhost redirected you too many times." How would I go about achieving this task with PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: You change the action attribute on your form element. Though if your form is actually using GET requests, it would be changed by your rewrite rules.

Comment: My current form element looks like this
<form id="aform" action="/news/" method="get">
What would I need to change?

Comment: mod_rewrite works the other way round: it rewrites what is typed into browser's address bar, or sent as link via action of a form _into_ `news?news_id=6` for your webserver. So put `news/6` into action and rewrite that in .htaccess to `news?news_id=6`

Comment: I figured. I'm sure that the only way I can achieve this is through PHP or JS.

Comment: Can't you redirect the user after the processing of the form by your PHP script ?

Comment: I tried to do so as shown in my question, but I'm met with a "localhost redirected you too many times." error on the browser.

Comment: That is because you are redirecting the page to the same page over and over again.

Comment: Why would you want to eliminate parameters at all? What is so bad with them? I frequently observe beginners trying to break well implemented standards. Much senseless effort which could be better invested in developing functionality.

Comment: Btw. repeated redirects on each submit are overhead and thus a performance impact.

Comment: There is nothing really "bad" about them, they are just simply ugly. Why would I want a url to look like /news/?news_id=6 when it can look like /news/6. One is obviously much prettier than the other.

Comment: The best and traffic saving method is to enable both URL forms, have a canonical link tag (because of duplicate content) and intercept the submit event via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but, does it have to be a 'get' form? If you want a clean URL this would be a very simple example with the post method (without any security checks!). You can leave the 'action' empty if it's the same page:

Form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    [Other form code ]
    <input type="hidden" name="news_id" value="6" />
</form>
```

Process code:

```
if ($_POST && !empty($_POST['news_id'])) {
    // Do what you want with: $_POST['news_id'];
}
```

Also, you could make a new mod_rewrite where you handle your form processing, like: /news6/process for example. This would be better for security reasons and you will have much cleaner code. After you have done your processing set a session variable to let the user know if the processing was completed or not on '/news/6'.

Comment: For this project I need to use get as the request method.